# Emulator screen is not showing in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator

I just installed Eclipse Mars and installed the SDK and all necessary files for the Android development, but when I start a new Android application project I have a total blank screen. Any button, text or anything I put on it just disappears. I am sharing the image of what I am seeing.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEozG.png)

Comment: Google have stopped supporting android development with eclipse long back. If you are just starting to develop in android , switch to android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reduce android sdk version to 4.1.2 (see Pic below)and you will be able to view all your views except layouts with Recyclerview Cardview,Navigation drawer, Pull to refresh layout as parent view .**

Google is trying to promote Android Studio and our beloved Eclipse is destined to be doomed.

[image: Change APK version]

**Though you will be able to compile and run material design UI with eclipse without any problem. It is just you will not be able to view layouts with material layouts as parent.**

Comment: and how can i do that? on this button i have only one option android 6.0